# Where can I find interesting Ubuntu discussions?

Tags: support, asking-questions, faq-proposed

Ask Ubuntu is a [Q&A site](https://askubuntu.com/faq) rather than a discussion board, a bug tracker, or a poll/survey site, but I really love Ubuntu and want to discuss those things with other users!

Where can I discuss topics that aren't appropriate to ask on Ask Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5):

*(Because this is proposed for our Community FAQ, please add to this answer.)*

[Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/) hosts discussion boards dedicated to Ubuntu.  The [Ubuntu Wiki](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/) is community-edited documentation of various kinds.

You can directly [participate](http://www.ubuntu.com/community/participate) in Ubuntu user groups and development, and you can find a [Local Team](http://loco.ubuntu.com) close to you if you want to help in your local area.  [Ubuntu Brainstorm](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/tour/) is for proposing and voting on ideas.

[Bug reports](https://askubuntu.com/q/5121) go on the project's preferred bug report site, or [Launchpad](http://launchpad.net/).  However, if you have a question about behavior you don't understand and aren't sure if it's a bug, or if you are asking for how to work around a bug, that is Q&A and appropriate for [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).

[Ask Ubuntu Chat](http://chat.askubuntu.com) is for talking to other AU users both about Ubuntu and about AU.  The [Ubuntu IRC channels](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IRC/ChannelList) are for discussion and support; you'll need an [IRC client](https://askubuntu.com/q/8015).

Ask Ubuntu Meta (this site) is for [discussion](http://meta.askubuntu.com/tags/discussion), [support](http://meta.askubuntu.com/tags/support), [bug reports](http://meta.askubuntu.com/tags/bug), and [feature requests](http://meta.askubuntu.com/tags/feature-request) about AU itself.