# Will 'askubuntu.com' be an alternative for the 'ubuntu forums'?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Hey,

I was wondering how to know the best place for your question? I was browsing the 'questions' section and I came across a numbers of problems that aren't just "questions", the same kind you'd find on the forums, so, is there a rule or something? or this site is going to be a better alternative for the forums?

Comment: I think askubuntu will be the favorite site for many users.

Comment: Here's some more info: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/234/why-this-over-the-ubuntu-forums

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find interesting Ubuntu discussions?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/627/where-can-i-find-interesting-ubuntu-discussions)

Answer (score 20):

- If you want to have a *discussion*, use forums.
- If you want to have a *final answer*, use AskUbuntu.

Comment: Quick and to the point. If only the whole site was like this answer.

Answer (score 13):

askubuntu (and every other stack exchange site) is designed for questions to which there is a definitive answer. Questions that either dont have a single answer, or the answer is likely to be subjective or opinionated, arent really for ask ubuntu.

The ubuntu forums, whilst you can still ask specific questions (and get good some very good answers), its also possible to start debates and / or more argumentative questions.

As to which is best, that depends, to get something done or to get something to work, ask ubuntu is probably the better tool. For reasoned debate, head for the ubuntu forums.

for more info on what you can ask, see here: https://askubuntu.com/faq

Answer (score 10):

I have read through a few questions on askubuntu that seem more like a discussion than question, and in most cases those who have been simply stating "opinions" have been reprimanded. As far as I know askubuntu is aimed at addressing issues or topics in the most objective manner possible. The Ubuntu-Forums however allow the users to be both objective and subjective; not always about addressing, but also discussing them.

Please let me know if that has been helpful.

Comment: I think that's from the flow of new users who still haven't quite figured out how the site works so they try to use it like a forum for a while until they figure it out.