# Can I share an Idea about ubuntu here?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I want ask here before share my idea in main **ask ubuntu**. i think it may be against the **website rules**.
so is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find interesting Ubuntu discussions?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/627/where-can-i-find-interesting-ubuntu-discussions)

Comment: [feature-request] is for requesting specific features; while [support] is for asking about problems using the site, [discussion] seems a better tag for this question.

Comment: @roger I only want to ask is it against the website rules or not :) / sorry I didn't know that, and thanks for editing

Comment: I understand, just trying to help you better understand the "required" tags too. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One place to share your ideas on Ubuntu is http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 4):

If your 'idea' isn't a question, then Ask Ubuntu probably isn't the place for it. If you have ideas for *discussion* then take a look at the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/).