# Are EFI/UEFI installation type of question appropriate at Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, scope

Searching "ubuntu-12-10 install uefi" gives a google page of Ask Ubuntu Q&A all pointing to same recommendation. (which is make a grub-efi partition before trying to install)
Have asked this type of Q myself (which is [How to EFI install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/208405/102029)) and the solution of making a grub-efi partition does not work on the hardware being used as the firmware needs a completely unallocated space drive to install any OS EFI mode. Additionally if Ubuntu did install EFI mode there is no way to manage it as the firmware/bios does not allow any obvious access to efi shell.
In my particular case just select dvd to efi;  make sure hard drive/sata is set to ahci then simply boot to dvd with installation media inserted.  Any os with a usable efi image/kernel will then boot installer efi mode.
However Ubuntu 12.10 does not install EFI mode for me; nor for many others.

There are known grub-efi and grub-legacy as well as partman issues which could make all this relative but as a conscientious newer user have been spending much time in FAQ and when trying to apply what is said in FAQ I personally seriously doubt that these type of Q should be asked here as i am thinking along the lines that this is actually a hardware/firmware or even manufacturer policy/attitude problem with regards to what information is provided for relating to the use of or management of an (U)EFI capable system - which could mean a lot of boot/installation type questions be asked unnecessarily or even be out with the scope or intention of this site.

Due to the non existence of any useful information regarding efi and how to manage an efi installed os from the manufacturer in my particular case has led me to here (trying to)using this site.

Grouping all UEFI, EFI and or all CSM, legacy questions together has proven to be limiting the potential of this site as there is much useful information regarding all these subjects (tags) that it is difficult to find due to poor provision of appropriate tagging.

When will motherboard manufacturers take the responsibility of providing useful information regarding EFI/UEFI on their products?.  My motherboard manufacturer website even shows download links which show a full UEFI type of interface is possible (on my specific boards webpage) but when asked why (as there is no access to it in bios/firmware settings or referenced to in motherboard manual)  they say it is just for reference. Yet another example of how unfruitful requesting appropriate information from manufacturer is.

Which is contributing to why many people feel the need to Q Ask Ubuntu to get answer specific to them. Manufacturers methods differ for mananging EFI/UEFI and therefor this type of Q could be considered not to be Ubuntu type question as it is specific to hardware/manufacturer or at least related to what information that manufacturers provide to the users of their hardware.

Thought would take the opportunity to open **discussion** here and Thank you for Ask Ubuntu!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't see why they wouldn't be on topic.

Questions about how to install Ubuntu, regardless of BIOS, UEFI, etc., are still within the scope of the [FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq)

Comment: Was hoping for a bit more filling in on why you see or how you see things the way that you do but found this to help get a realistic perspective of what is and what is not off topic -"However, if you have a question about behavior you don't understand and aren't sure if it's a bug, or if you are asking for how to work around a bug, that is Q&A and appropriate for Ask Ubuntu." which is quoted from http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/628/102029 It may not be subject but **how** it is asked that makes things on or off topic!?

Comment: @geezanansa The question you asked didn't specifically ask for details.  Does the question ask about Ubuntu installation (minus Alpha/Beta/Development) installation?  It's on topic.  About Alpha/Beta/Development? Offtopic because beta.  About a non-ubuntu release?  Also offtopic because it's not ubuntu.  Otherwise, the FAQ is quite decent, and does include questions about EFI/UEFI/Hybrid-EFI installation (because "General Installation QUestions") as within the scope of the site.

Comment: why have i seen questions tagged with 13.04?

Comment: why have i seen questions tagged with 13.04?  That is if it is off topic as it is not released yet.  In my opinion a fact is a fact meaning unchangeable regardless of how zoomed in or out the scopes are! :)

Comment: @geezanansa you asked the same question twice, you know that right?  I haven't had a clear answer yet from the mods yet as to how they're handling that.  AFAIK it's still OT, but...