# Tag creation request: [hybrid-efi]

Tags: discussion, tags

Would like to ask if anybody would find it helpful creating [hybrid-efi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hybrid-efi)?

Hybrid-efi is efi compliant but is different to use especially when trying to install Ubuntu. Different manufacturers use different efi management options. The hybrid-efi system i use does not use efi shell and does not have any efi gui. No efi/uefi device name appears in one time boot list or bios settings. Firmware is efi compliant but is basically bios with an efi compliant system which firmware manages "automagically".  Which proves very difficult to manage especially if ESP gets corrupted as there appears to be no means of restoring the necessary files back to ESP. That is on a non-linux install and have not as yet achieved an Ubuntu install to a gpt -efi mode using hybrid efi system.

So from a user point of view hybrid-efi is very different from efi/uefi capable machines that do use shell prompt as well as having gui.

For a more accurate description of what is specifically involved differing hybrid-efi and what is involved to install Ubuntu to this type of firmware; **you could look [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gb-hybrid-efi/)**.
This is the only informative and educated source i can find regarding the subject.

Am sure I am not the only one using this particular version of efi system so thought would open discussion to get some feedback regarding how many or how few people would find this request useful.
One question to which all this relates to can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208405/how-to-hybrid-efi-install-ubuntu-12-10).  The answers to which show it is presumptuous to assume UEFI related answers are appropriate.

**Maybe a more experienced user with the appropriate privileges may think it helpful or useful if this tag was created in the accepted manner.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [hybrid-efi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hybrid-efi) tag does not currently exist. (I don't just mean that no questions are currently tagged with it. It doesn't exist at all; *no question* has recently been tagged with it, and it probably never has existed. You can verify its nonexistence by [typing it in here](https://askubuntu.com/tags).)

Tags are only synonymized once they exist. Tags are created by a question being tagged with it (either originally, or in an edit). A tag is never created without a question.

Users with 300 or higher reputation can create new tags. There are many such users, but this tag has never been created (at least not yet). That suggests we may not need it.

Furthermore, you say:

> So from a user point of view hybrid-efi is very different from
>   efi/uefi capable machines that do use shell prompt as well as having
>   gui.

It sounds like you're saying [hybrid-efi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hybrid-efi) has a *substantially different meaning* from [uefi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/uefi) or [efi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/efi). If that's the case, it shouldn't be a synonym at all.

To synthesize these two arguments: The tag doesn't exist, so we don't know for sure how people would use it. If it is created and turns out to express the same thing as [uefi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/uefi), then it should be made a synonym. If it's created and turns out to express something different, then it should be kept as a separate tag. Either way, new tags shouldn't be created artificially to be made synonyms--instead, we should wait for it to be created. If it ever is, we can see *how it is being used here* and act accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that [tag:hybrid-efi] has to be created.  May i request any user with appropriate privileges create this tag. It may be appropriate to ask an appropriately qualified person to retag my question to which the original post relates.  hybrid-efi deserves a tag related to my question at least.  Every tutorial i have seen tries to cover both efi and uefi and as it has been unclear as to why they have not been useful to a hybrid-efi system; which is because an hybrid-efi system has no efi shell or efi gui.

Comment: To many readers efi is no different to uefi which both do have their own tags. Do hope have highlighted why hybrid-efi is as different to efi as efi is different to uefi and therefor hybrid-efi desreves it own tag and (as it is associated with uefi) as an synonym of master tag uefi

Comment: Maybe "efi" "hybrid-efi" and "uefi" all should have their own tags as you suggest. Do see the point you make.

Comment: @geezanansa are there any questions that exist that would need this tag?  As it stands, unless a moderator is able to arbitrarily create new tags, a question would need to exist that would get the initial tag.  Do you know of such a question?

Answer (score 3):

Tag created, but without a tag wiki.  Anyone's allowed to reverse that by removing the tag from the question and then vaporizing the tag, but since there seems to be a suggestion that's been agreed on to keep [hybrid-efi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hybrid-efi) separate from other tags, i've created it.

Now all it needs is a good tag wiki entry.

NOTES:
[DONE] Create [hybrid-efi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hybrid-efi)
[FACT] No tag synonym needed.
[TODO] Mods to set a status tag on this as they see fit. (my suggestion is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) maybe, because the tag has been created in accordance with the discussion and opinions on the other answer here)

Comment: Guess what my next question is...  lol

Comment: @geezanansa add it to the question (which I did), or create the tag wiki?  Last I checked, tag wikis can be submitted by anyone, they just need approvals.  I may be wrong on that though

Comment: The meta question here http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6392/are-efi-uefi-installation-type-of-question-appropriate-at-ask-ubuntu may have other points of interest which may or may not affect the outcome of the decision regarding [tag:status-completed].

Comment: @geezanansa I think the +10 upvotes on my response saying that installation related questions about [tag:hybrid-efi] questions relating to installation support the on-topic nature of such questions.  So I don't think there's any change in the outcome of this, yet.