# Suggest Tag-Create [tag:legacy-bios]?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

Many questions relating to driver, installation and boot problems if search for "legacy"; thought it would be good to suggest create tag [legacy-bios](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/legacy-bios) to help narrow folks search results when using tags as search tool.

Do not have required privileges to do this myself so it would be appreciated if somebody could do so on my behalf. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think "legacy-bios" is really a necessary tag until the knee-jerk reaction to UEFI is no longer "turn it off".

Comment: Due to my reputation and privilege level am afraid that i can not put much more input to that- other than keep on posting.  Perhaps talking to someone rather than about them could be more constructive?  Referring to FAQ using tags as search tool is the very intention of having tags.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say there.

Comment: "I don't think "legacy-bios" is really a necessary tag **until the knee-jerk reaction to UEFI is no longer "turn it off"**  What knee-jerk reaction are you referring to exactly?  My own, yours or others?

Comment: For a while all the uefi answers were turn it off as a workaround.  Now, there are several answers that actually cover using it, but some people I talk to are in the camp of "it's pointless to use it anyway" or "pay ms tax to have a boot-time feature", or any number of other responses.  A more suitable solution might be to detag all questions that are tagged both uefi AND bios and leave bios and uefi tags separate, possibly with a legacy-bios synonym to just bios.  Tagging as uefi and bios is redundant.

Comment: try reading question and or How do i search? section of FAQ. Tags are search tools right?

Comment: I've read the faq.  It's becoming apparent you just don't like that I disagree.

Comment: "Tagging as uefi and bios is redundant" if there was a legacy tag i could see your point

Comment: Come to chat if you want to talk.  We had this same discussion on tagging questions with computer models.  It just adds loads of useless tags that don't make search any faster.

Comment: Will try chat later on if that ok to give you a shout later

Comment: Have tried editing my question http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6392/are-efi-uefi-installation-type-of-question-appropriate-at-ask-ubuntu to try and better highlight my concerns/observations related to why this tag create request was made

Comment: I agree with your conclusion, but not the justification. I don't think that a decision about this should be based on the popular opinion of EFI. It's quite plausible that some day "legacy" BIOS support will be officially phased out and we'll be obligated to make the transition regardless of our knee-jerk reactions.

Answer (score 2):

Not many systems actually are shipping with UEFI and such, yet.  A lot of systems on the market still use BIOS.  Therefore, I don't see a need for this tag until UEFI becomes the standard for systems on the market.

Comment: Why are there so many related U/EFI questions? Do agree that legacy is being used as a descriptive term for BIOS.  There are many questions referring to legacy bios when searching Ask Ubuntu. The tag request was made to help current Ask Ubuntu users search Ask Ubuntu more easily.

Comment: @geezanansa "legacy-bios" suggests that there is an older version of BIOS that is legacy.  BIOS != U/EFI therefore if they have a question about BIOS, they can still use the BIOS tag.  I fail to see why we need to classify BIOS as "legacy".  With legacy-grub and grub2, that's a different story (as an example), since grub2 actually replaced grub1 and grub1 was renamed to legacy-grub.  But BIOS is not going to be renamed to "legacy BIOS", I don't think, so... why do we need to rename it to be called "legacy-bios" when we call it "bios" regardless?

Comment: Do not mean to appear unreasonable and am sure you understand that a tag has to be created before it can be added as synonym.   Totally agree with and see the point you are making regards the definition of BIOS. It is only U/EFI capable machines; (that use CSM or Hybrid-EFI for example) that refer to booting using BIOS as Legacy. The example you use of Grub2 and grub-legacy is a good one as is grub-efi.

Comment: My understanding is they are all different from grub1 which is now known as grub-legacy whereas Grub2 uses grub-bios and grub-efi(check any wiki) Due to the volume of U/EFI problems that appear to be similar thought would post here for discussion and request tag create in order to see how people would use it; if at all. I really do think it (legacy-bios) may be beneficial for tagging questions as it indicates an U/EFI capable system and be useful as a search tool.

Comment: I don't think you'll find support on this, until "Turn UEFI off" is not the current action, you're getting zero support from me.  And it seems others are also agreeing with me on that (see the other answer)

Comment: I really do not mind you disagreeing with my request.  I really do think it laughable, unreasonable and dishonest to recommend "Switch it off".  That is a perfect example of how this site is not fulfilling the purpose of its existence.  On observing highly knowledgable and accurate answers not being acknowledged as such and throughout history there are examples of how the majority are more than to often wrong due to unreasonableness and haughtyness and for just plain convenience sake.  The first people to argue that the earth is round cost them their lives for example.

Comment: "A decision has been made and that is that" is neither reasonable nor intelligible.

Comment: @geezanansa to spare myself and all of Ask Ubuntu my hangover-induced raging today, I've asked jokerdino to take a look here and decide whether your arguments have merit, or whether or not me and the others are agreed on "we're not making this tag" or similar.  once a mod says it, that will end our argument.  Also, if you want to CONTINUE to argue, you can come find me on chat.  Mods are there too and can render decisions.

Comment: @geezanansa There's not enough support and consensus in creating this tag. So, let's leave it for a while and come back later (may be some couple of months). This discussion right now is not going anywhere and there are better things to do with life. Cheers.